# c# How can i know if a certain process is running on a remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, remote-access

I would like to know please, in c#, how can i know if a certain process is running on a remote machine ?

The remote machine is in my network and i will alwyz be using the same user.
Thanks

Comment: WMI can easily be used remotely, as far as I am aware.

Comment: what is WMI exactly ? I'm looking for a way with only c# if possible

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation has even an example in C#.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use System.Diagnostics to check the local computer and then use.

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses("machineName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I will say that you could use WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx

So you need to develop a small server listing processes on a computer and serving them through Object.

There is may be a easier way but this one for sure works.